# When to Call Method after Property Change

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, event-handling

I have a User Control that contains a list of items and I raise an event when the currentIndex changes, also, when it changes, I must call two other methods two verify and change the appearance of the Control (change an Image and block/unblock some buttons).

What I want to know, mostly out of curiosity because it is already working, is when is it more appropriate to call these two methods?

Should I call them within the `CurrentIndex` property per se? Should I call them within the `OnCurrentIndexChanged(...)`? Should I handle the event within the class and do it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume you've implemented the standard event generating pattern and made OnCurrentIndexChanged `protected virtual` so that a derived class can override the method and alter the event generation and/or handling.

Unfortunately that requires reading tea leaves, *why* would anybody want to override the method?  And more seriously, *how* could overriding the method break your control when they do?  That's awfully hard to guess at for anybody that doesn't know the code well, not exactly easy for you either.  The principle to apply here, used in the .NET framework code as well, is to do as little as possible.  Just raise the event, nothing else.  Which minimizes the odds of breakage when the derived class does something silly, but entirely common, like not calling base.OnCurrentIndexChanged.

The behavior of your controls is an implementation detail of your UserControl.  So change their properties in your CurrentIndex property setter, then call OnCurrentIndexChanged().  Anybody that derives from your class can override that behavior, if necessary.  And nothing goes wrong when they forget to call your OnCurrentIndexChanged() method. But do note that you need to make the control variables *protected* instead of private.  So they *can* override the behavior, if they need to.

And don't hesitate to just not use a virtual method at all if this is too spooky for you.  It's not common to have to accommodate hundreds of thousands of programmers with your controls :)

Comment: Considering the fact that the inheriting class can actually override my base class puts some perspective into the approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the user control, I would have a property that represents the selected item.  Then, during the setter of the object, raise the event method to change your user control. That way, in the future, if you need to add more listeners, you just need to add another handler in the setter method.  This is pretty common in MVVM applications and is pretty maintainable.

Comment: That is basically what I have, with the diference that you don't set the object itself but the index of the object, and in the setter of the index I raise the event. What I don't know is if I should call the other methods within that same setter? or within the method that raises to the event? or within a delegate inside the same class? or any other place you guys come up with.

Comment: @PedroC88 I would call each method from the setter of the property.  I've seen that used plenty and it becomes easy to add methods once the control gets more complicated.  That's pretty much the crux of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and abstraction.

Comment: that's how I have it right now actually, I call both methods in the setter of the property, I just wanted to see if there was a better approach (and why). It seems we agree there. P.S. I'm not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Because your UserControl acts as a ListControl, you need to implement two events and two properties.

```
public event System.EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;
public event System.EventHandler SelectionChangeCommitted;

public int SelectedIndex {
    get;
    set;
}

public T SelectedItem { // Where T is whatever your type is
    get;
    set;
}
```

`SelectedIndexChanged` should always be used for actions that always need to be triggered when your selected index is changed. `SelectionChangeCommitted` should *only* be triggered when the user physically changes the selection. The separation between the two is an important distinction, and most controls in .NET follow this pattern (eg. ComboBox), but may not use the same name for the events.

Now, with that said, if the controls you need to change properties for are also within the same user control, then you should of course handle that within the user control code in the appropriate event. Otherwise, the code should be orphaned to whoever implements the user control (eg. a form or another user control) by subscribing to the event and doing the work there.

The order really depends on your requirements, but `SelectedIndexChanged` should *always* be raised (but not more than once per change as that would introduce strange behavior), and again `SelectionChangeCommitted` should only be raised by the user (eg. setting SelectedIndex or SelectedItem).

A good rule of thumb is if your internal stuff MUST happen before the user knows about it, call SelectedIndexChanged first, then SelectionChangeCommitted. If it doesn't matter, either or. Changing the order later on could result in breaking changes in whoever implements the control, so make sure your decision is solid.

The difference between the two is SelectedIndex and SelectedItem would be updated by things like clearing your list internally, adding new items, et cetera, but does not necessarily mean it was a physical user action that should result in both your events firing.

Hope this helps.